# Function "typeof" declared implicitly on RVDS 5.01

Tags: c, arm, typeof, rvds

I was compiling modem codes with ARM compiler for android phones.
I got the error below:

```
function "typeof" declared implicitly
```

Then I though I should use `__typeof__`. But I got the same error：

```
function "__typeof__" declared implicitly
```

I even tried `__typeof`. But none of them works.

Why?

The compiler is RVDS 5.01. 
The command line is contained in some scripts.

The error message is:

```
"/opt2/huanglianjun/PD1401V-modem-1.2.1.c1/boot_images/core/storage/ext4/src/com‌​mon/div64.h", line 47:
Error: #223-D: function "typeof" declared implicitly.
```

The code is :

```
#define do_div(n,base) do{  \ 
      uint32_t __base = (base); \ 
      uint32_t __rem;   \ 
      (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0));    \ 
      if (((n) >> 32) == 0) {   \ 
          __rem = (uint32_t)(n) % __base;   \ 
          (n) = (uint32_t)(n) / __base; \ 
      } else    \ 
          __rem = __div64_32(&(n), __base); \ 
          __rem;    \ 
    }while(0)
```

Comment: Perhaps your particular compiler does not support the typeof extension. Show us some relevant info: 1. Your compiler name and version. 2. The command line used to compile your code. 3. The exact error message you get. And preferrably 4. The code you compile, a minimal code example that shows the same error.

Comment: The compiler is RVDS 5.01. The command line is contained in some scripts. The error message is: "/opt2/huanglianjun/PD1401V-modem-1.2.1.c1/boot_images/core/storage/ext4/src/common/div64.h", line 47: Error:  #223-D: function "typeof" declared implicitly. The code is #define do_div(n,base)  do{    \
 uint32_t __base = (base);   \
 uint32_t __rem;     \
 (void)(((typeof((n)) *)0) == ((uint64_t *)0));  \
 if (((n) >> 32) == 0) {   \
  __rem = (uint32_t)(n) % __base;  \
  (n) = (uint32_t)(n) / __base;  \
 } else      \
  __rem = __div64_32(&(n), __base); \
 __rem;      \
 }while(0)
@nos

Comment: What compiler flags are you using? A manual I found suggests that RVDS supports some GCC extensions including `typeof`, unless `--strict-ansi` or `-ps` is given.

Comment: I believe some versions of RVDS requires the --gnu flag to enable some of the gcc extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read [the documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205g/Caciegea.html) right, `typeof` is supported since at least RVDS 3.0, but you need to enable [GNU mode](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0205g/Caceiccb.html) by passing the `--gnu` flag to `armcc`.